# Distribution of Interop files

Tags: c#, com

There are some bug fixes that have been done in a COM component. Each time I compile, a new interop file is generated along with the dll of the actual component (component.dll) where the fix has gone in. Is it necessary to release the interop file (interop.component.dll) along with the actual dll when releasing the fix to the customer.

Also, I would like to know what exactly does interop files have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the COM components interface remain unchanged then you will not need to replace the interop   library.

Interop files are containing automatically generated wrapper classes for you COM interfaces, so you can call your COM components without worrying about the correct order and type of your method parameters.